# Asterisk - Wrap up time on Outbound Call

Tags: queue, asterisk, pause, outbound

Is there a way to manually set up wrapuptime for 'OUTBOUND' queue in Asterisk?. What i want to achieve is when agents makes an outbound call (successful) after hangup he is paused for i.e. 10 seconds before either taking inbound call or making another outbound call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use astdb, hangup handler, dialplan check.

Plan is like that:

1) Before call check ${DB(/CHECK/${CALLERID(num)})} value if it exist or if time in it less then 10 sec in past.

2) Setup hangup handler for this call.

3) In hangup, put current timestamp to DB(/CHECK/${CALLERID(num)}), so it can be checked in 1) for next call.